# How to create a Enum with a abstract method that returns a generic type that can be a Functional Interface like functions, consumers, suppliers

Tags: java

I have a Enum that have a field `value` and a abstract method that returns a generic type that can be a functional interface to each constant will have your particular behavior.

```
public enum TestEnum {

    PERIOD("PERIOD") {
        @Override
        public <T> T operation() {
            return () -> Map.of(
                    "INIT", LocalDate.now()
                            .minusDays(1L)
                            .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())
                            .minusMonths(1L),
                    "END", LocalDate.now()
                            .minusDays(1L)
                            .minusMonths(1L)
                            .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())
            );
        }
    };

    private final String value;

    public abstract <T> T operation();
}
```

In this can return a supplier but I have other scenarios that can return a `Function`, and `BiConsumers`.

Doing this I'm receiving a error that required type `T` but I'm providing a `lambda expression`.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Being picky - don't run this code very close to midnight or the dates will be very wrong. Perhaps you mean `public abstract <T> Supplier<T> operation();` and concrete definition  PERIOD `public Supplier<Map<String,LocalDate>> operation() `

Comment: Its just an example :D thanks @DuncG! If I made this change the method only will accept Suppliers, but in this case I need to accept Consumers, Functions, etc as well. Is there a way to be more flexible is this case?

Comment: don´t know if you can do this with enums but you can do a pseudo enum with a class with static variables and a wrapper class  that houses the string and the function

Comment: This does not look like a good use case for enums.  Create a set of static constants somewhere, each of which can have their own type, instead of trying to use an enum you'll have to cast everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

A version using a general `Function` might allow you to declare other arbitrary operations:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    PERIOD("PERIOD") {
        @Override
        public Function<Void,Map<String,LocalDate>> operation() {
            return xxxNotUsed -> Map.of(
                    "INIT", LocalDate.now()
                            .minusDays(1L)
                            .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())
                            .minusMonths(1L),
                    "END", LocalDate.now()
                            .minusDays(1L)
                            .minusMonths(1L)
                            .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())
            );
        }
    };
    TestEnum(String x) { value = x;}
    private final String value;

    public abstract <T,R> Function<T,R> operation();
}
```

Note that I've used `Void` as a dummy parameter type for the "Supplier" style of call you wanted for `PERIOD`, and you could use `Function<XYZClass,Void>` for "Consumer" style of operation.

Comment: Thanks! This works! Intellij complains about this `Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion. Found java.util.function.Function<java.lang.Void,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDate>>', required 'java.util.function.Function<T,R>' ` but working fine.
And when I simulate a "Consumer" I have to declare a return explicit `return null` for instance.